# Two different formulas for ${\frac {\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A}}$, what am I missing?

Tags: tensors

[This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)#Derivative_of_the_inverse_of_a_second-order_tensor) names two different formulas for ${\frac {\partial A_{ij}^{-1}}{\partial A_{kl}}}$, with $A$ being a second-order tensor. What I think is supposed to be the general case is written as

$${\frac {\partial A_{ij}^{-1}}{\partial A_{kl}}}=-A_{ik}^{-1}~A_{lj}^{-1}.$$

Then there's a second version that is specified for "if the tensor $A$ is symmetric", which is written as

$${\frac {\partial A_{ij}^{-1}}{\partial A_{kl}}}=-{\cfrac {1}{2}}\left(A_{ik}^{-1}~A_{jl}^{-1}+A_{il}^{-1}~A_{jk}^{-1}\right).$$

Now to my understanding, for a symmetric tensor $A$ both of these are supposed to hold because symmetric is just a special case of a general tensor. If I'm not mistaken, for both the formulas to be true at the same time it would require $$A_{ik}^{-1}~A_{lj}^{-1} = A_{il}^{-1}~A_{jk}^{-1},$$ which I'm pretty sure is not true for a general symmetric tensor $A$? (At least the numerical example I tested gave different values.)

What am I missing here? Does the formula for the general case somehow require $A$ to be non-symmetric? Why are there two different formulas for what appears to me to be the exact same thing?

Comment: I suspect the context of "if $A$ is symmetric" carries the implication that as $A_{kl}$ varies, $A_{lk}$ also does so as to remain equal. Hence that version of the formula involves two terms.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the response. So are you saying the first formula doesn't hold for symmetric $A$ because of that?

Comment: It might be instructive to explicitly compute all the derivatives (wrt $a,b,c,d$) for the case of a $2\times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{a & b\\c & d}$ and for a symmetric matrix $\pmatrix{a & b\\b & d}$ and compare to the formulas.

Comment: @Winther Not sure what you mean exactly. I mean, we already have the explicite results in index notation in the question body, what more insight than that could we gain?

Comment: This was in ref to what was mentioned above. Note that in the second case $A_{12}=A_{21}$ so a derivative wrt $b = A_{12} = A_{21}$ will be different than in the first case.

Comment: Take the case of differentiating the determinant (just because its simpler to see) $\frac{d\det A}{dA_{ij}}$. In the first case $\det A = ad-bc$ so $\frac{d\det A}{db} = -c$ while in the second case $\det A = ad-b^2$ so $\frac{d\det A}{db} = -2b$. The whole point is that there would be a difference if $A_{12}$ is treated as the same variable as $A_{21}$ than both being independent variables.

Comment: @Winther Good example, thanks, will look into that.